# Gulp 4 Split Tasks Across Multiple Files Using Gulp-Hub Fails Due to Missing Get Function

Tags: gulp, gulp-4

Using Gulp 4 and the [recipe](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/4.0/docs/recipes/split-tasks-across-multiple-files.md) for splitting my tasks into multiple files using gulp-hub throws this error just from attempting to load the task files. The task file is super simple just wanted to test everything was working.

I found this reference on Undertaker on Github for the [get](https://github.com/gulpjs/undertaker-registry#gettaskname--function) function, but I really don't understand what they are trying to say, and it seems like gulp-hub is supposed to be doing the lifting.

Anyone else run into this and know how to solve it?

**Gulp File**

```
'use strict';

var gulp = require('gulp');

var HubRegistry = require('gulp-hub');

// Load some files into the registry
var hub = new HubRegistry(['gulp/tasks/*.js']); // only one file help.js

// Tell gulp to use the tasks just loaded
gulp.registry(hub);
```

**Help Task - /gulp/tasks/help.js**

```
'use strict';

var gulp = require('gulp');

gulp.task('help', []);
```

**Error Thrown**

```
$ gulp help
[01:36:37] Loading gulp\tasks\help.js

D:\projects\app\node_modules\undertaker\lib\helpers\validateRegistry.js:36
      throw err;
      ^
 AssertionError: Custom registry must have `get` function
    at validateRegistry (D:\projects\app\node_modules\undertaker\lib\helpers\validateRegistry.js:28:5)
    at Gulp.registry (D:\projects\app\node_modules\undertaker\lib\registry.js:17:3)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\projects\app\gulpfile.js:11:6)
    at Module._compile (module.js:541:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:550:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:458:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:417:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:409:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:468:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are probably running `gulp-hub@0.8.0` which is the version that is currently published to [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-hub) and is designed for gulp 3.x.

For gulp 4.x you need to install `gulp-hub` from one of the [development branches on GitHub](https://github.com/frankwallis/gulp-hub/branches). Currently there's `4.0` and `registry-init`.

The `4.0` branch doesn't work right now because it fails the [registry validation](https://github.com/gulpjs/undertaker/blob/d1f423d/lib/helpers/validateRegistry.js#L30) of `undertaker`.

The `registry-init` branch seems to work however. You can install it like this:

```
npm uninstall gulp-hub
npm install --save-dev frankwallis/gulp-hub#registry-init
```

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it

Comment: As of 2017-12-31 gulp-hub can be simply installed using `npm install --save-dev gulp-hub@next` (same tag as `gulp` uses since the same date)

Answer (score 1):

Update on 12.10.2016

I work with yeoman-fountainjs and in their package.json is the following dev-dependency definied, which works like a charm:

```
"gulp": "gulpjs/gulp#4ed9a4a3275559c73a396eff7e1fde3824951ebb",
"gulp-hub": "frankwallis/gulp-hub#d461b9c700df9010d0a8694e4af1fb96d9f38bf4",
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same error but it was because I failed to expose the tasks correctly to Gulp.

At first I was using CommonJS like this in my `help.js` file and getting the same error:

`exports.help = help;`

So I changed it to a Gulp task and it worked:

`gulp.task("help", help);`