# How splite gulpfile tasks into different file on gulp 4 without any package like gulp-hub?

Tags: javascript, split, gulp

I am trying to split my gulpfile tasks into different files. I did it before and add it into main gulpfile by just adding `require('./path/taskName')`
But this is not working in gulp 4

this is my `styles.js` file:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    postcss = require('gulp-postcss'),
    autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer'),
    cssvars = require('postcss-simple-vars'),
    nestingCss = require('postcss-nested'),
    cssImport = require('postcss-import');

function styles(){
    console.log('Changes happened in CSS file');
    return gulp.src('./public/styles/style.css')
    .pipe(postcss([cssImport, cssvars, nestingCss, autoprefixer]))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/temp/styles'));
}

 exports.styles = styles;
```

and this is my `watch.js` file

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();

function html(done){
    console.log('Changes happened in html');
    browserSync.reload();
    done();
}

function cssInject(){
    return gulp.src('./public/temp/styles/style.css')
        .pipe(browserSync.stream());
}

function watch(done){
    browserSync.init({
        server: {
            baseDir: "public"
        }
    });
    gulp.watch('./public/**/*.html', html);
    gulp.watch('./public/styles/**/*.css', gulp.series(styles,cssInject));
    done();
}

exports.html = html;
exports.watch = watch;
```

I added this into main gulpfile

```
require('./gulp/tasks/styles.js');
require('./gulp/tasks/watch.js');
```

but this is not working.It shows an error of

```
$ gulp watch
[20:27:30] Using gulpfile ~\Desktop\gulp-website\gulpfile.js
[20:27:30] Task never defined: watch
[20:27:30] To list available tasks, try running: gulp --tasks
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gulp 4 Split Tasks Across Multiple Files Using Gulp-Hub Fails Due to Missing Get Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38522329/gulp-4-split-tasks-across-multiple-files-using-gulp-hub-fails-due-to-missing-get)

Comment: This link told about gulp-hub but i did it before by just adding require('./gulp/tasks/styles.js'); without any package.
is it possible in gulp 4?

Comment: Did you take a look at the second answer, which suggests changing `exports.html = html;` to a gulp task like so, e.g.: `gulp.task("html", html)` ?

Answer (score 5):

You can still do it but in a different way:

1. With require-dir package (or you need index.js file where you export all your tasks: watch, html, styles):

   ```
   // gulpfile.js
   var tasksNotInAGulpfile = require('require-dir)('./gulp/tasks');
   exports.watch = tasksNotInAGulpfile['watch'].watch
   exports.styles = tasksNotInAGulpfile['styles].styles
   ...
   ```
2. The easiest solution for you:

   ```
   // Main gulpfile (gulpfile.js)
   var stylesTasks = require('./gulp/tasks/styles.js');
   var watchTasks = require('./gulp/tasks/watch.js');
   exports.styles = stylesTasks.styles;
   exports.watch = watchTasks.watch;
   exports.html = watchTasks.html;
   ```

For gulp to see your tasks they have to be exported with ***module.exports*** or ***exports*** like in the previous example.

Let me know if that helped.