# Trouble with splitting gulpfile.js into multiple files in Gulp 4

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-4

I am a beginner to Javascript and Gulp. Am learning this based on a udemy course in which Gulp 3 is being used, and I've been looking at docs to convert the code to Gulp 4. It's been fun so far since I am learning more when I am doing the conversions myself, but am stuck on this one. Wonder if you guys can offer some advice.

**Issue**: When I split the gulpfile.js into separate files to organise my files better, it starts throwing errors. Code below.

**styles.js**

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    postcss = require('gulp-postcss'),
    autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer'),
    cssvars = require('postcss-simple-vars'),
    nested = require('postcss-nested'),
    cssImport = require('postcss-import');


function styles(cb) {
    return gulp.src('./app/assets/styles/styles.css')
    .pipe(postcss([cssImport, cssvars, nested, autoprefixer]))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./app/temp/styles'));
    cb();
}

exports.styles = styles;
```

**watch.js**

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();


function cssInject(cb) {
    return gulp.src('./app/temp/styles/styles.css')
    .pipe(browserSync.stream());
    cb();
}

function browserSyncReload(cb) {
    browserSync.reload();
    cb();
}

function watch(cb) {
    browserSync.init({
        notify: false,
        server: {
            baseDir: "app"
        }
    });
    watch('./app/index.html', browserSyncReload);
    watch('./app/assets/styles/styles.css', gulp.series(cssInject, styles));
    cb();
}

exports.browserSyncReload = browserSyncReload;
exports.watch = watch;
```

**gulpfile.js**

```
var stylesTasks = require('./gulp/tasks/styles.js'),
    watchTasks = require('./gulp/tasks/watch.js');

    
exports.watch = watchTasks.watch;
exports.styles = stylesTasks.styles;
exports.browserSyncReload = watchTasks.browserSyncReload;
```

When I run "gulp watch", this is what I get.

**error**

```
$ gulp watch
[21:14:28] Using gulpfile ~/Projects/travel-site/gulpfile.js
[21:14:28] Starting 'watch'...
internal/async_hooks.js:195
function emitInitNative(asyncId, type, triggerAsyncId, resource) {                      ^

RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
(Use `node --trace-uncaught ...` to show where the exception was thrown)
```

I found another post with almost identical code, but with a different error - which happened to be one of the errors i was getting earlier as well, and have followed the solution mentioned in that post - and that's when I get this error.  Here's the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55477268/how-splite-gulpfile-tasks-into-different-file-on-gulp-4-without-any-package-like#) to the post.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question feels wierd, but I found the solution after playing with it for couple of days. See below.

I needed to import styles into watch.js, and not gulpfile.js. That was my first mistake. To do this, I added the below line to watch.js

```
var styles = require('./styles').styles;
```

Then my gulpfile.js only needed two lines

**gulpfile.js**

```
var watchTask = require('./gulp/tasks/watch').watch;
exports.default = watchTask;
```

I also removed the variable gulp, instead created variables for src and dest. So, the rest of the code looked like below.

**styles.js**

```
var {src, dest} = require('gulp'),
    postcss = require('gulp-postcss'),
    autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer'),
    cssvars = require('postcss-simple-vars'),
    nested = require('postcss-nested'),
    cssImport = require('postcss-import');

const styles = function (cb) {
    return src('./app/assets/styles/styles.css')
    .pipe(postcss([cssImport, cssvars, nested, autoprefixer]))
    .pipe(dest('./app/temp/styles'));
    cb();
}

exports.styles = styles;
```

**watch.js**

```
var styles = require('./styles').styles;
var {src, series, watch} = require('gulp'),
    browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();

const cssInject = function (cb) {
    return src('./app/temp/styles/styles.css')
    .pipe(browserSync.stream());
    cb();
}

const reload = function (cb) {
    browserSync.reload();
    cb();
}

const watchTask = function (cb) {
    browserSync.init({
        notify: false,
        server: {
            baseDir: "app"
        }
    });
    watch('./app/index.html', reload);
    watch('./app/assets/styles/styles.css', series(cssInject, styles));
    cb();
}

exports.watch = watchTask;
```

Hence resolved! hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

I have a full article that shows many how to regarding going from gulp3 to gulp4, I think you are going to find everything you need [there](https://razmo.ca/sitecore-build-script-with-gulp-js-4/)

But basically, I think you need to take a look at these modules :

- [gulp-task-loader-recursive](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-task-loader-recursive)
- [gulp4-run-sequence](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp4-run-sequence)
- [require-dir](https://www.npmjs.com/package/require-dir)

Then, from a gulp.js perspective, you can end up with something like this :

```
// gulpfile.js

global.config = require('./gulp/config/config.json');

require('events').EventEmitter.prototype._maxListeners = 1000;

require('require-dir')('./gulp/tasks/styles');
require('require-dir')('./gulp/tasks/watch');
//... etc ...
```

So you would be able to then create your styles task and export it :

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
postcss = require('gulp-postcss'),
autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer'),
cssvars = require('postcss-simple-vars'),
nested = require('postcss-nested'),
cssImport = require('postcss-import'); 

function styles(cb) {
    return gulp.src('./app/assets/styles/styles.css')
    .pipe(postcss([cssImport, cssvars, nested, autoprefixer]))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./app/temp/styles'));
    cb();
}

const stylesTask = task('styles', styles);
exports.stylesTask = stylesTask;
```

You can then validate its recognized by gulp :

```
gulp --tasks
```

If you correctly see your styles tasks, you should now be able to run your task by running :

```
gulp styles
```

Repeat those steps for the watch task.

Comment: Thanks for your reply dude - much appreciated. although i think i found the solution after playing with it for 2 days. Posted below.